# How to Find Path to Qt in MacOSX

Tags: macos, qt

I'm trying to deploy a Qt app in mac. The instructions say to configure Qt as a static library. For that, I need to navigate to the path of Qt and run the `./configure -static` command. However, I cannot find the correct path to input this command. How can I find the correct path?

Comment: How did you install Qt?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I installed Qt from the binary package.